# What is the diffrance between API Manager and Intergration Server?

Tags: wso2

I am new to WS02. So I just want to understand what the difference is between API Manager and Integration Server.

I did not know about this software and it looks awesome. What I want is to orchestrate automation across systems using an ESB but also have a store to manage the API's. Do I install both or just the API Manager ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with software development. Possible belongs on ServerFault?

Comment: This is where they state where we should ask questions. https://wso2.com/community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually 'orchestrate automation' you will need the Enterprise Integrator. Enterprise integrator is also a product that you generally don't want to expose to the outside world ie. the big bad internet.

The API Manager serves exactly that purpose. It is a gateway you can use to expose resources while managing access, availability, throttling etc. However, it is not meant to build actual integrations/orchestration etc.

In your case it sounds like you would need both.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. It sounds like this software will work very well for my needs.